# Can't read JSON file in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http, post

I want to read a JSON file from the file system but I can't make it work.

I've found this solution that seems to be what I need: [Is it possible to upload a JSON file though file upload and read the contents in Angular 6 without talking to an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53666616/is-it-possible-to-upload-a-json-file-though-file-upload-and-read-the-contents-in)

But i get two errors:

Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type on  `uploadFile(event) {`

and

Object is possibly 'null' on `console.log(reader.result.toString());`

This is my code:

component.html:

```
 <form name="JSONform" (ngSubmit)="fJSON.form.valid && decryptJSON()" #fJSON="ngForm" novalidate>
        <input type="file" name="files" (change)="uploadFile($event)" />
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="decrypt">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Decrypt</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

component.ts:

```
 uploadFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length !== 1) {
      console.error('No file selected');
    } else {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = (e) => {
        console.log(reader.result.toString());
        // handle data processing
      };
      reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }
```

I don't know what I'm missing.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything. These errors are TSLINT or TypeScript errors. Just got to check for them:

```
// Tell TS that you mean it as any (or you can find the actual event d.ts
// Use the ? operator to check for nulls (or do an if( reader.result != null)
// before calling toString()
uploadFile(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files.length !== 1) {
      console.error('No file selected');
    } else {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = (e) => {
        console.log(reader.result?.toString());
        // handle data processing
      };
      reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you really much! Now it works